# Is there a way to set all dates?

Tags: sql, date, set, dbt

I was wondering, in SQL/dbt is there a way to set all dates to be >= another date?

Say I have a 'createdat' date field and a 'updatedat' date field. I use it multiple times in my query (multiple CTEs) as well as other dates. I want to make sure all dates used are less then the last day of last month (i.e. <= last_day(current_date()-30, month)).

Is there a way to set that in the beginning of the query?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: sure, define and set a variable.

Answer (score 3):

This can definitely be done. You'll want to compare the `greatest()` of a number of columns with whatever date cut-off you want.

Effectively, it would be:

```sql
select *
from {{ ref('some_table') }}
where greatest(created_at,updated_at) < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

You can obviously add as many columns to that query as you'd like.

**N.B.**: On some warehouses, `greatest` returns `null` if *any* of the columns in it are null. In that situation, you'll need to coalesce each date with some date placeholder, like '1970-01-01'.